# How to center electron popup window dialog showOpenDialog

Tags: popup, electron

I want file open popup to be initially centered, but instead it appears in left top corner of the screen and consequently remembers position where it was closed.

```
dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow,{title:`Open ${type} file`,buttonLabel:'Open'})
```

I've been taking a look on docs but i cant find center option.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way to set the `x`, `y` position of an Electron dialog via the Electron [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog) API.

- On Microsoft Windows, Electron dialog's open in the top left corner of the parent window.
- On MacOS, Electron dialog's open in the top centre of the parent window.

Whilst it is possible for dialogs to open in the centre of the screen, or at a set `x` `y` position relative to a parent window or screen using a lower-level language, this is not possible via the Electron API only.